# Counting factors: is this approach in the literature on multiperfect numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, open-problems, powerful-numbers

Does the following approach (or something near it) exist in the number theory
literature?

I will provide some motivation for [$\omega(p^n - 1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134716/omegapn-1-as-n-rightarrow-infty)
and for this question.  First, I recall that $\sigma(m)$ is the sum of positive
divisors of the natural number $m$, and that
$m$ is an $n/d$-multiperfect number when for coprime
natural numbers  $n \gt d $  one has $nm=d\sigma(m)$.
Perfect numbers are the case $n=2$ and $d=1$.

Now here is an attack on the Odd Perfect Number Conjecture, with perhaps
an extension to some odd $n/d$-multiperfects.  Most perfect numbers are
mostly powerful, where I  mean all but one prime factor of the
perfect number occurs with multiplicity greater than one. (6 is provably
the sole exception to this characterization.)  Indeed, all known existing
perfect numbers $m$ satisfy $\log(m) \lt 2\omega(m)$. (Here as in the
linked post above, $\omega$ counts prime factors with multiplicity, so
$\omega(75)=3$.)  While we may not expect the same inequality for
odd perfect numbers, because they are mostly powerful, they should
have more prime factors than most numbers of roughly the same size.

If we write the equation above for perfect numbers, using a prime
factorization for $m$, we get that $2\prod p_i^{e_i} = \prod\sigma(p_i^{e_i})$,
or in terms of $\omega$, $1 + \sum e_i = \sum \omega(\sigma(p_i^{e_i}))$.
Now there is very little control over $\omega(\sigma(p_i^{e_i}))$ when $e_i=1$,
but there are things to say when $e_i \gt 1$, and when the factors of
$\sigma(p_i^{e_i})$ are limited to a finite set, this says a lot about $e_i$, and
in particular may imply very few factors and a very special relationship
between $p_i$ and the other prime factors.

We may not be able to dispose of the conjecture entirely, since there may be
one factor of $m$ which is  one less than a largely composite number, but
we might be able to constrain that one prime and use some other information
to rule out the existence of $m$.

I am aware of (but not well versed in)  Kevin Hare's lower bounds on $\omega(m)$
for odd perfect $m$.  Is there any other work on $\omega$ and multiperfects,
even if they aren't trying to rule out odd perfect numbers?  I would especially
appreciate a paper in the odd perfect literature that entertains the above approach.

Comments or suggestions for improving/focusing the question are welcome,
as are downvotes with accompanying rationale.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's asking us to check his approach to some old open problem.

Comment: The intent is not to check the approach. The intent is to check the collective memory to see if someone remembers an approach similar to or even mildly resembling this.  If someone says "this reminds me of paper X", that remark may prove useful.  I will do the research regardless, but if someone has a useful pointer, that will speed things up for me.  Or is what I am asking not a reference request?

Comment: You say - "Most perfect numbers are mostly powerful, where I mean all but one prime factor of the perfect number occurs with multiplicity greater than one." - The definition of *powerful numbers* (as they are currently used in the literature) are in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number) and [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerfulNumber.html), so I think you are using the terminology "powerful" in a different context here.  Nonetheless, I would like to refer you to the following [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419281).

Comment: Additionally, it is $\Omega(75)=\Omega({3}\cdot{5^2})=1+2=3$, not $\omega(m)$, which gives the number of prime factors of $m$, counting multiplicities.  (In fact, $\omega(m)$ actually gives the number of *distinct* prime factors of $m$.)

Comment: Since all (currently) known perfect numbers are even, using your context and "own" terminology, you claim that the perfect numbers $m$ satisfy $\log(m)<2\Omega(m)$.  Plugging in the Euclidean form for (even) perfect numbers, you are actually claiming that $$2(\Omega({2^{p-1}}({2^p} - 1))) = 2((p - 1) + 1) = 2p > \log(m) = (p - 1)\log(2) + \log({2^p} - 1).$$

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2p+%3E+%28p+-+1%29%28log+2%29+%2B+log%28%282^p%29+-+1%29+) confirms that your inequality is indeed true, for even perfect numbers.  I would be curious to know if a similar inequality holds for odd perfect numbers.

Comment: Working from the Eulerian form $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ for an odd perfect number (i.e., $\gcd(q,n) = 1$ and $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), your inequality leads to

$$k\log(q) + 2\log(n) < 2\Omega({q^k}{n^2}) = 2(k + 2) = 2k + 4,$$

which yields

$$k(\log(q) - 2) + 2\log(n) < 4.$$

But since $q$ is the *special/Euler* prime (with exponent $k$),

$$k \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \Longrightarrow k \geq 1,$$
$$q \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \Longrightarrow q \geq 5,$$

and most especially, since $q \leq q^k < n^2$ [JIS Article 12.4.4](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) and ... [continued]

Comment: we have the recent lower bound ${q^k}{n^2} = N > {10}^{1500}$ for odd perfect numbers (by [Ochem and Rao](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/)), we obtain the (nontrivial) lower bound $n > {10}^{375}$.  This essentially contradicts your inequality *up to several orders of magnitude*.

Comment: You say - "While we may not expect the same inequality for odd perfect numbers, because they are mostly powerful, they should have more prime factors than most numbers of roughly the same size." - Again, the statement "odd perfect numbers are *mostly powerful*" is *still* an open problem, and it is in fact the subject of my current papers on the topic.  See [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5991) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2329) if you are interested to know more.

Comment: A final note:  You asked for a reference request.  While this particular paper's approach is not directly related to what you are currently trying to do, you might get some (equally useful) ideas by perusing the recent [paper](http://www.maths.soton.ac.uk/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf) by Broughan, et. al.  That would be all for now - shoot me an e-mail if you have any questions.  =)

Comment: Jose, thank you for your comments and the reference.  If you would like, perhaps we could try a chat room.  I think your computation of $\Omega(q^kn^2)$ above has an error; but I point out the inequality to emphasize that perfect numbers have lots of factors, and if I were more careful I would say Euler proved that odd perfect numbers are either powerful or mostly powerful, if they exist at all.

Comment: Yes, indeed -- great catch!  If $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is the Eulerian form of an odd perfect number, *and* if $N = {q^k}\prod_{i=1}^{\omega(N)-1}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$ is its canonical (i.e., *prime*) factorization, then $\Omega(N) = k + \sum_{i=1}^{\omega(N)-1}{\alpha_i}$.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger, I was already able to locate the chat room you have created earlier.  I would rather prefer if you will just shoot me an e-mail... :)