# Reference request: Research done on whether the Euler prime can be the largest factor of an odd perfect number

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, open-problems

(Note:  This was cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138363).) I posted the following reference request in MSE three (3) days ago, but was unable to elicit any responses.  I am cross-posting it to MO, hoping that it is *appropriate* for this site.

I would like to request references to research done as to whether the Euler prime of an [odd perfect number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) can also be its largest factor.

To be more specific, the Euler prime $q$ of an odd perfect number $N$ is the *sole* 
prime factor that occurs to an (odd) exponent $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  That is, we can write this odd perfect number in the form $N = {q^k}{n^2}$, where $\gcd(q, n) = 1$.

In an e-mail, it was communicated to me by [Douglas Iannucci](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=26955) that his adviser, [Peter Hagis Jr.](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=26966), considered this possibility.

I was wondering if anybody here knows of any partial results in this direction.

Thank you!

[Added Feb 8 2015] We do know that the Euler prime $q$ is not the smallest prime factor of an odd perfect number $N = {q^k}{n^2}$.  To see why, it suffices to consider:

$$q + 1 = \sigma(q) \mid \sigma(q^k) \mid 2N.$$

Comment: Perhaps give a *good reason* for your very quick downvote?  =)

Comment: All votes are anonymous for a reason. Asking for a reason is ok, but I just wanted you to know that this has been discussed and people think anonymity is good. See this meta discussion for details: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/828/55893 (And no, I didn't vote in either direction.) Perhaps the downvoter hints that this question is not appropriate for MO.

Comment: Maybe.  But based from the length of time it took the voter to downvote, I am guessing he/she did not bother to even check if results for which I am requesting a reference are well-known/easily searchable in Google/readily available.  Indeed, a quick survey of search results in Google for "largest prime factor" "odd perfect number" "Euler prime" would return my own papers @LOL@.

Comment: I also found Samuel Dittmer's [Spoof Odd Perfect Numbers](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2014-83-289/S0025-5718-2013-02793-7/S0025-5718-2013-02793-7.pdf).  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.math.missouri.edu/~bbanks/papers/2008_Descartes_Final.pdf) by Bill Banks et al. studies spoof OPN's similar to Descartes' spoof, and of course in Descartes' spoof the "quasi" Euler prime is the biggest prime.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Do you or does Bill have an idea about odd multiperfects?  I'm looking for literature which may touch on the idea in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134826/counting-factors-is-this-approach-in-the-literature-on-multiperfect-numbers , and anything which has a similar smell to it.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: In my recent paper "Odd perfect numbers, Diophantine equations, and upper bounds" (which you can find on my website) I prove an upper bound on odd multi-perfect numbers in terms of the number of distinct prime factors.  You may find that useful.

Comment: I also found Samuel Dittmer's [Spoof Odd Perfect Numbers](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2014-83-289/S0025-5718-2013-02793-7/S0025-5718-2013-02793-7.pdf).  =)